# ASP:CHART legend check box series control

Tags: c#, mschart

I have a fully functioning Dynamic chart control( just the regular ASP.net Chart ) It works great but I've run into a problem trying to add check boxes to the legend. I'm trying to add them next to the series names so the user can hide or view the respective series data. The chart is plotting data for roughly 42 employees. So being able to select and hide data is very important. I've been researching this for a few days now and I've found examples for 3rd party chart tools but i need to do this in MSVS 2010 standard charting tool.

This is how I create the Chart.

```
 for (int emp = 1; emp < empRowList.Length; emp++)
        {
            chartB.Series.Add(empRowList[emp]);
            chartB.Series[empRowList[emp]].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
            chartB.Series[empRowList[emp]].MarkerSize = 10;
            chartB.Series[empRowList[emp]].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Star4;            

            for (int month = 1; month < 12; month++)
            {
                    chartB.Series[empRowList[emp]].Points.AddXY(mfi.GetMonthName(month), employeeStats[month, emp]);
                    chartB.Series[empRowList[emp]].Points[chartB.Series[empRowList[emp]].Points.Count - 1].ToolTip = empRowList[emp] + " - " + employeeStats[month, emp];                   
            }
        }
```

Here is how I format the chart

```
 chartB.DataSource = t.Tables["info"];
 chartB.DataBind();
 chartB.Legends.Add(new Legend("Legend"));
 chartB.Legends["Legend"].Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
 chartB.Legends["Legend"].Docking = Docking.Top;
```

I looked through this post thinking it could be augmented to help but since his series aren't added dynamically i'm not  sure if it is the right direction to pursue.

[ASP .net 4 Chart Control Legend formatting is not displaying at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485460/asp-net-4-chart-control-legend-formatting-is-not-displaying-at-all)

I've also looked in to using custom legends but read that they aren't linked to the data so i thought that might also be that wrong direction.

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated i'm kind of at a stand still till I can figure this out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution similar to what i wanted using the code from the link above but could never quite get the legend to work properly so i scrapped that idea and just dynamically created a check-box bank underneath my chart that hides/shows series. Wasn't too difficult just needed to create a class and deal with the click event verses the redraw of the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Some code on this would have been wonderful as I was looking to do something similar.

I did however find a post on msdn that states custom legends are not possible.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677428(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: This should probably be a comment.